# Unable to assert css width to be 100%

Tags: javascript, css, testing, bdd, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to assert the CSS width of an element in NightwatchJS to be 100%, but it fails saying that the width is 196px. The error message is :

> Testing if element <[data-e2e="base-button"][class="xs block"]> has
>   css property "width: 100%". - Expected "100%" but got: "196px"

I have tried using the following syntaxes for the same:

```
page.assert.cssProperty(`@button-element`, 'width', '100%');
page.expect.element(`@${element}`).to.have.css("width").which.equals("100%");
```

I don't want to use hard-coded values, as they can change depending on the container width. What is the right way to do it?

I'm using Page Object Model here but can do without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you first get the width of the parent, then the width of the child and do a comparison between them to calculate the percentage?

I don't use nightwatch myself, but the psuedo code from what you've described above should be something along the lines of:

```
const {expect} = require('chai');
let buttonParentSize = page.get.cssProperty(`@button-parent`, 'width'),
    buttonSize = page.get.cssProperty(`@button-element`, 'width'),
    buttonSizePercentage = (buttonSize / buttonParentSize)*100;

expect(buttonSizePercentage).to.equal('100');
```

Comment: Thanks, @Kyle. I am trying to create generic step definitions, which can interpret cucumber feature definitions. And a person writing those features is not supposed to care about these intricacies.

Comment: You could use xpath to locate the elements, which would make it easier for those people. `//*[contains(@class, 'button-continue')]` for the button and `//*[contains(@class,'button-continue')]/..` for the parent - and then follow the same logic as above. The only change then would be for class, id, name (whatever you want to select with the xpath) and do a comparison with it's direct parent. You could make this a function for added usability

Comment: Let me try @kyle and see how it goes.

Comment: I tried the approach and got success. Thanks a lot.

Comment: {      return api.getElementSize(elementA, function (resultA) {
        return api.getElementSize(elementB, function (resultB) {
          return api.perform(() => dumbAssertion(resultA.value[property], resultB.value[property]));
        })
      })
}

Comment: ignore my last comment, here is what I wanted to write:

I used "css-to-xpath" package to generate xpath out of the elementA's css selector. And then just added "/parent::*" in the end to get the parent element.


`
    let parent = cssToXPath.parse(elementA).toXPath() + '/parent::*';     
    page.api.getElementSize(element, function (resultElement) {
        page.api.useXpath().getElementSize(parent, function (resultParent) {
          page.api.perform(() => {
            page.assert.equal(resultElement.value.width, resultParent.value.width);
          });
        })
      })
`

Comment: Hi @kyle, do you think we should add the code I mentioned in the comment above to the answer, for reference?